# Как отсортировать класс по его свойствам ?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Нужно отсортировать класс "Shop" по возрастанию свойства "price",
я реализовал таким образом:

```js
    sortProductsByPrice(dataset, order, prop) {
        let sorted = dataset.sort((a, b) => {
            return order(a[prop], b[prop])
        });
        return sorted;
    }
let res = shop.sortProductsByPrice(shop.products, (a, b) => a - b, "price");
console.log(res);
```

Но это не правильно, в моей задаче стоит подсказка  в виде вызовов. 
Они должны выглядеть вот так: `sortProductsByPrice (sortOrder)` 
и вызов: `console.log(shop.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC));`
Помогите понять, что  нужно делать

### Вот весь код:

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }
    //method for sorting the product at its price
    sortProductsByPrice(dataset, order, prop) {
        let sorted = dataset.sort((a, b) => {
            
            return order(a[prop], b[prop])
        });
        return sorted;
    }
}

const shop = new Shop();
// create products
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 2", 1, 700));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 3", 2, 800));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 4", 3, 1000));
//sort by the specified key "price"
let res = shop.sortProductsByPrice(shop.products,
    (a, b) => a - b, "price");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: ну так используй не `prop`, а `"price"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашим подсказкам должно быть что-то вроде этого.

Только есть один нюанс - исходный массив `products` тоже сортируется.

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
  constructor(name, count, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.count = count;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC = 1;
Product.SORT_ORDER_DESC = -1;
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
  constructor(products) {
    this.products = [];
  }

  //method for adding a product
  addProduct(newProduct) {
    this.products.push(newProduct);
  }
  //method for sorting the product at its price
  sortProductsByPrice(order) {
    let sorted = this.products.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.price > b.price ? order : -order;
    });
    return sorted;
  }
}

const shop = new Shop();
// create products
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 2", 1, 700));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 3", 2, 800));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 4", 3, 1000));
//sort by the specified key "price"
let res = shop.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
console.log(res);
console.log(shop.products);
```